# LightGBM: How can I use scale_pos_weight in case of multiclass classification?

Tags: python, multiclass-classification, lightgbm, imbalanced-data

LightGBM official document says 'scale_pos_weight' can be used to control weight of labels with positive class.

https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html

However, I'm trying to solve multi-class classification. The targets are encoded as 0, 1 and 2.

The target 0 takes 30% portion of total samples. And the target 2 takes 10% portion of total samples. And the target 1 takes 50% portion of total samples. So the classes are imbalanced.

How can I use scale_pos_weight to solve this multi-class classification?

Do I have to encode target which has relatively small sample size as positive? After that do I have to encode target which has relatively large sample size as negative?

Answer (score 0):

For this, you would want to use the `class_weight` parameter, as per the [LGBMClassifier docs](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html#lightgbm.LGBMClassifier).